# Captions of subfigures not being centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

[image]

Figure 4.1 is two subfigures, each with a caption (technically four figures in total, but the ones on rows are one image).

Using

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,titlepage]{report}

 \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

\geometry{
  body={7in, 10in},
  left=0.75in,
  top=0.5in
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
       \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=8.7cm]{fig5-a.png}
      \caption{\textit{I-V Charactaristic at 1Hz (left) and 5 Hz (right)}}
   \end{subfigure}
       \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=8.7cm]{fig8.png}
      \caption{\textit{I-V Charactaristic at 10 Hz (left) and 500Hz (right)}}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{I-V Charactaristics of varying frequencies, showing the expected tightening of the bow}
    \label{fig:freqdep}
 \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

the captions are not aligned under the entire figure. Ideally the caption would spread right across the width of both plots in figure 4.1 a

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for the sample code.  In the future, please include a **full** [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, including all necessary packages, and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified the width of each subfigure to be `0.3\textwidth`, and that sets the width of the caption.  But the included graphic is much wider, so it sticks out.

To fix, set the width of the subfigure to be the full column width:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[ht]
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig5-a.png}
         \caption{\textit{I-V Charactaristic at 1Hz (left) and 5 Hz (right)}}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig8.png}
          \caption{\textit{I-V Charactaristic at 10 Hz (left) and 500Hz (right)}}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{I-V Charactaristics of varying frequencies, showing the expected tightening of the bow}
      \label{fig:freqdep}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(Thanks to egreg for the helpful comment.)

Comment: This has made the text central to the entire page?
http://i.imgur.com/NJQJDg3.png

Comment: @TheRandom: That's weird.  I wasn't working with a two-column document.  Update your MWE to accurately recreate the problem and I'll take another look.  (But not immediately; I'll be away for the next few hours.)

Comment: Use `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth`. I'd use the same or a fraction of it (say `0.9\columnwidth`) instead of `8.7cm` which is just a guess.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the comment.  I've edited.

Comment: The `\textit` could be moved to the `subcaption` package options: `\usepackage[textfont=it]{subcaption}` so there is no need for repeating `\textit`s anymore.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: thanks for that tip.  When testing I determined that `\textit` in the caption doesn't affect the typesetting of the list of figures, so I opted to not optimize out that bit.  Or advise on the use of the `siunitx` package ...

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Oh yes, you are correct, I didn't thought about the List of Figures. (But I think it would be a better idea to adapt that in a different way, e.g. using `tocloft`.)